# How to get related model in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have models:

```
class Model_1(models.Model):
    name = ...
    [...]

class Model_2(models.Model):
    model_1 = models.ForeignKey(Model_1)
```

and now I get model_1 objects in view, and in template I want to get model_2:

```
{% for m in models_1 %}
    {{ m.model_2 }} ?????
{% endfor %}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it:

```
{{ m.model_2_set.all }}
```

You can change model_2_set if you define the related name. There is not changes if this is in template or in a view